# Get rows based on column value

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE employee(emp_no NUMBER,
                      emp_id VARCHAR2(50),
                      emp_type NUMBER)

INSERT INTO employee(emp_no, emp_id, emp_type) VALUES (1, 'John', 100);   
INSERT INTO employee(emp_no, emp_id, emp_type) VALUES (2, 'Sam', 200);
```

I need to write a query for employee table where emp_type is 100, on the above data I'll get one row but  if emp_type is not 100 for any of the employees, 
like:-

```
INSERT INTO employee(emp_no, emp_id, emp_type) VALUES (1, 'John', 200);   
INSERT INTO employee(emp_no, emp_id, emp_type) VALUES (2, 'Sam', 200);
```

then I need all the rows.

Looking for simple query to achieve that. Thanks in advance

Comment: just use `not in` or `not exists` operators. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about performance, you could do something like this (not tested, as I am just trying to show the general idea):

```
select * from employee where emp_type = 100
union all
select * from employee
     where not exists (select * from employee where emp_type = 100)
;
```

If performance is important, I believe the following solution may be better:

```
select emp_no, emp_id, emp_type
from   ( select e.*, count(case when emp_type = 100 then 1 end) over () as ct
         from   employee e
       )
where  emp_type = 100 or ct = 0
;
```